# bash ls command not found on mac osx

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

Having an issues with my terminal. Every time I tap in a command such as `ls` i get

```
Patricks-MacBook-Pro:~ patrickwalsh$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
```

Running

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

fixes it but only temporarily. If I close the window and reopen for example then I am back to the above problem.

Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: When the problem occurs, what does `echo $PATH` give you?

Comment: It returns the following Patricks-MacBook-Pro:~ patrickwalsh$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_rc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

and remove any other `PATH`-declarations (like the one above).

Answer (score 0):

When making a PATH declaration in your ~/.profile, make sure you append ":$PATH" so the contents in the original PATH variable do not get lost.

For example, if your .profile has:

> export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/bin/python

The shell will have lost reference to the "stock" commands due to the second declaration. Instead, a simple change to the second EXPORT line

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin/python:$PATH

should fix the problem!